# Probability involving interval lengths

Tags: probability, integration

The real numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$ are chosen randomly in the interval $(0, 1)$. Let $I_1$ be the interval between $x$ and $y$, and $I_2$ be the interval between $z$ and $t$. Define $|I|$ to be the length of interval $I$. Find the probability that $|I_1 \cup I_2| > \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is in the interval $(0, 1)$.

The part I'm struggling with is how do I represent this as an area/volume which I could integrate - could someone please explain the intuition behind coming with an integral to represent probabilities which can be used to solve such questions, thanks.

Comment: Note that the interval $I_1$ can be expressed as $(\min\{x, y\}, \max\{x, y\})$ and $|I_1| = \max\{x, y\} - \min\{x, y\} = |x - y|$. For union interval, you need to consider whether the two intervals overlap.